# Why is null value getting converted into string "null"?

Tags: java, javascript, string, null

I have a form at the client side in JavaScript which has a field named `commEmail`.

When user hit submit, the commEmail remains null and it is sent back to the back end which is in Java.

Here, the commEmail that I get it being converted in a string "null" instead of identifying it as a null. How can i fix that?

This is my code

```
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{userId}") // specifies the relative path for a resource class
    public void updateUser(@Auth Jwt jwt,
            @FormParam (value="firstName") String firstName,
            @FormParam (value="lastName") String lastName,
            @FormParam (value="commEmail") String commEmail,
            @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
```

// Here when i look into the values, the value of commEmail is "null" (a string) instead of null.

Comment: First of all, an empty field will be sent as an empty string, not as `null`. Whatever you're using for the back end may *convert* that to `null` (which would be wrong, IMO), but it's sent empty. A null string's string representation is `"null"`. What other processing do you do on `commEmail`?

Comment: I don't do any processing on commEmail. at the client side, i am just ending the object with commEmail = null. So, what you are saying is that I should rather send it as an empty string?

Comment: String concatenation of null can result in a "null"  String. Are you doing any concatenation?

Comment: How are you viewing this null value on the back end? Is it a database value you're finding with a query? What other process if any is used to get data from your form into the view you're seeing it?